# Find bifurcations of $x' =x^6 - 2 x^4 + \mu $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the family of ODEs given by $x' =x^6 - 2 x^4 + \mu $ for $\mu \in R$.

We want to find the bifurcation points for this family, ie the points where the number of solutions changes.

I can certainly [plot this equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E6%20-2%20y%5E4%20%3D%20-x) and find the bifurcation points graphically, but I was hoping to find an analytical way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one-dimensional autonomous equations of type $\dot{x} = P(x, \mu)$ all bifurcation values can be found from solving the system
$$ P(x^\ast, \mu^\ast) = 0, \, P'_{x} (x^\ast, \mu^\ast) = 0.$$

This is basically because all bifurcations in 1d case happen only with equilibria (this is why we have the first equation) and equilibrium becomes non-hyperbolic iff the derivative $P'_{x} = 0$ at it (and it is the second equation). In your case it means:
$$ x^6 - 2x^4 + \mu = 0, 6x^5 - 8x^3 = 0,$$
which transforms to
$$ x^2 = \dfrac{4}{3}, \, x^6 - 2x^4 + \mu = 0,$$
and finally
$$ x^2 = \dfrac{4}{3}, \, \mu = \dfrac{32}{27}. $$

At $\mu = \dfrac{32}{27}$ two equilibria coalesce at $x = \sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}}$ and $x = -\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}}$. This is because technically it's the only bifurcation that can happen in 1d autonomous equations.

Comment: How do we check that no other equilibria exists when $\mu = \frac{32}{27}$?

Comment: I suggest to divide $x^6 -2x^4 + \mu$ by $x^2 - \dfrac{4}{3}$ when $\mu = \dfrac{32}{27}$. This would give your a polynom of lesser degree which would be more susceptible for analysis. By the way, I just described what typically happens in such bifurcations and I should admit that this wasn't thorough analysis.

Comment: I also was a bit inaccurate because I forgot that at $\mu = 0$ there is also a bifurcation at $x = 0$. This can be clearly seen from the graph that you've attached to your question.